# Use native node name for a Polymer custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a custom Polymer element which contains an array of items, rendering them as a table. I'd like to add a custom element that handles the rendering of each row in the table, but the custom element is not allowed in HTML at the point where `<tr>` would normally be added.

Allowed:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Not allowed:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <custom-row>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
  </custom-row>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've seen [examples of Web Components that use an "is" attribute to extend native elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) (e.g. `<tr is="custom-row">`), but [that doesn't seem to be possible in Polymer's template binding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html).

I'm working around this by either rendering the whole table in a single custom element, or using `div`s (with CSS for `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell`, etc) rather than table/tr/td elements.

Is it possible to keep using `<tr>` as the node name for a custom element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, presuming `<custom-row>` is a custom element extending `<tr>`, you're trying to nest a `<tr>` as a child of a custom one. The parser will throw that out.

Instead, use a type extension custom element (the `is=""`) form and extend `<tr>`:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr is="custom-tr">
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This worked for me: http://jsbin.com/nobaqeso/1/edit

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought I'd tried `is=""` before, but apparently not (or hadn't done it properly).